# Best place to store Javascript widget parameters (Front/Back-end)?

Tags: javascript, html, widget

I'm working for an online travel agency and we are building a mini search engine that our partners can insert into their website.

This is a JS+HTML snippet, not an iframe. Something similar to Google Adsense:

```
<!-- Widget code to paste in partner page -->
<script async src="//example.com/minisearch.js"></script>
<ins class="minisearch-engine"
 style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
 data-param1="ca-1597538769368159"
 data-param2="6301833493"
 data-* = '...'
</ins>
```

The widget has around 10 parameters (maybe more coming) regulating: background image, default destination, size ...

The debate is open where to store the configuration of the widget:

1. **Frontend** by the partner: directly in the parameters of the script or in data attributes of the "ins" tag.
2. **Backend** in our database: the widget just have an ID and the configuration is stored in the database. On request we load the configuration and build the widget for the partner.

What would be the best practice/arguments?

**EDIT** (lists of arguments for each side):

**FRONTEND:**

- Fast solution

**BACKEND:**

- More flexible in case of parameters changing value
- Possibility to check is the website calling the widget is a valid partner
- Long term maintenance
- No backward compatibility required

Comment: If you place it in your backend, your server will have to respond to every user who want to load your widget. But if you somewhere in the future want to change configuration the better way is to store it in db. It depends if you will be changing numbers of parameters or even changing values of parameters.

Comment: This is a quite new and "unstable" project. We don't know how it will evolve (number of parameters, their value).

Comment: Generally it is a good idea to put parameters in frontend. Google maps do it that way. Having params in db gives you possibility to change them in future but you must consider backward compatibility. Why not assume some params as default and put them as attributes of <isn> when needed to override? Or use some javascript initialization when adding your widget to the page? Many plugins do it that way

Comment: Regarding backward compatibility, I think that backend storage avoid this issue as you control everything (parameter and code). The client just have to call the initialization script with his ID. Google Adsense does it this way :)